# what does "had" in this sentence mean

Tags: grammar

> We loved our sports pavilion, maybe because it reminded us of those
> sweet little cottages people always **had** in picture books when we were
> young.

what does "had" mean in this sentence?
and what is point to use it?I think without it the sentence will become more nature

Comment: "…people always in picture books…" is nonsense.

Comment: sorry,I thought  cottages people was a compound noun.but what how do you know had in that sentence mean "had live in " instead of meaning by possession as "have" in " I have a car".people possess a cottage,which don't make sense?

Comment: @CN.hitori  "cottages people" doesn't make sense as a compound noun, because when we make a compound noun in English, we use the singular, like "*cottage* people", not the plural like "*cottages* people".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quoted text contains an example of ellipsis, where a word has been omitted without destroying the meaning for a native speaker. This is often done, especially in speech, to avoid repetition or for brevity. A more exact or more formal writer might have written 'those sweet little cottages **which** people always had in picture books'.

In this case, the word omitted is 'which', a relative pronoun. These can be omitted if the meaning would be clear without them:

> An ambulance came to take the climber (whom) I helped.
> The hunter (who) my sister saw in the woods was caught by the police.
> The train (which) she was about to take was late.
> This is the terminal (that) I told you about.
> That’s the seat (which) my ticket has written on it.

[Omission of relative pronouns](https://open.books4languages.com/english-b1-grammar/chapter/omission-of-relative-pronouns/#:%7E:text=The%20omission%20of%20relative%20pronouns,the%20subject%20of%20the%20clause.)

[Ellipsis](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/ellipsis)